# sql query into raw query in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new in laravel . I have laravel 5.7 version. and I have query

like

```php
$emp_id = $request->user_id;

$User_workDone_record = DB::select(
    DB::raw("
        SELECT
            (
                SELECT access(id) FROM users where id = $emp_id
            ) as accessid,
            a.date as date,
            a.day as day,
            a.projectname as projectname,
            a.clientname as clientname,
            task,
            start,
            (
                SELECT users(id) FROM `users` where id = $emp_id
            ) as user,
            end,
            TIMEDIFF(end,start) as diff,
            workdetails,
            id,
            rowpages
        FROM
            workdone as a
        where
            a.user = '$emp_id'
        order by
            a.date desc
    ")
);
```

but I got issue like :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION workdoneerp.access does not exist (SQL: `SELECT(SELECT access(id) FROM users where id=9) as accessid, a.date as date,a.day as day,a.projectname as projectname,a.clientname as clientname,task,start,end,TIMEDIFF(end,start) as diff,workdetails,id,rowpages FROM workdone as a where a.user='9' order by a.date desc)`,

How to resolve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `access(id)` at the start of your SQL query.

The error is telling you the `access()` function does not exist in your database (`workdoneerp`).

To solve it you can

- create the `access()` function
- or don't use the `access()` function.